# apachesolr autocomplete on large database

Tags: drupal, autocomplete, solr

Hi i m using apache solr 3.1 with drupal
i have integrated apachesolr_autocomplete in my development machine and it is working fine
but not updated on production server which has more than 40,000 records
can anyone suggest me that autocomplete would worK fine on large database?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have jQuery UI Autocomplete working with geonames.org, which has about 6 million place names worldwide.  I get roughly 1 second response time, and I believe much of that is internet latency. Autocomplete is not your issue. Its fast. How fast is your database with the query response?